# Difference between 母 and 妣

Tags: word-choice, nuances, nouns

What is the difference between 母{はは} and 妣{なきはは}?

Comment: What kind of dictionary are you using? I'm sure most native speakers don't know 妣, and I haven't even remember seeing this kanji in my archaic Japanese class at high school.

Comment: @naruto I'm using site jisho.org to learning and search kanjis.

Comment: Actually jisho.org is full of rare kanji and words which even native speakers can't read. One thing I recommend is to double-check the word with [ALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/), which is a large e-dictionary targeted at native Japanese audience. If ALC don't know some kanji, it probably means ordinary Japanese people don't know that kanji, either :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

母 is a very common term for mother. 妣 is rarely used nowadays and usually understood as "late mother", but it may be used as a variant of 母.

> 母に万葉で「妣」の字を宛てたのは、歿後の父母なる事を示したと言ふ事も出来ようが、唯母と通用したものだらう。そして、唯色々な形の歌を組み入れたゞけと見る方がよい。 ([折口信夫 相聞の発達](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000933/files/46954_27952.html))

Comment: You rather say "late mother" in English.

Comment: @macraf I knew 'dead' here wasn't appropriate but couldn't find the right one (I thought of *deceased*, which wasn't what I needed). Very much appreciated, thank you!